# Multilevel select on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use multiple select drop-down between several models

I have this:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
  belongs_to :city
end
```

when I select a city I want to pull list of items from selected city and show it on next drop-down list. How do I create relationships between drop-down menus ? Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](http://pullmonkey.com/2008/03/30/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails/) may help you in doing it.

**Rails 2 + Prototype**

*app/models/cities.rb*

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
  has_many :reports, :through => :regions # this is newly added
end
```

*cities_controller*

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @cities  = City.find(:all)
    @regions = Region.find(:all)
    @reports   = Report.find(:all)
  end

  def update_regions
    # updates regions and reports based on city selected
    city = City.find(params[:city_id])
    regions = city.regions
    reports   = city.reports

    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'regions', :partial => 'regions', :object => regions
      page.replace_html 'reports',   :partial => 'reports',   :object => reports
    end
  end

  def update_reports
    # updates reports based on region selected
    region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
    reports  = region.reports

    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'reports', :partial => 'reports', :object => reports
    end
  end
end
```

*_reports.html.erb*

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :report_id, reports, :id, :title,
                     {:prompt   => "Select a Report"}) %>
```

*_regions.html.erb*

```
<%= collection_select(nil, :region_id, regions, :id, :name,
                     {:prompt   => "Select a Region"},
                     {:onchange => "#{remote_function(:url  => {:action => "update_reports"},
                                                      :with => "'region_id='+value")}"}) %>
<br/>
```

*index.html.erb*

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= collection_select(nil, :city_id,  @cities,  :id, :name,
                      {:prompt   => "Select a City"},
                      {:onchange => "#{remote_function(:url  => {:action => "update_regions"},
                                                       :with => "'city_id='+value")}"}) %>
<br/>
<div id="regions"><%= render :partial => 'regions', :object => @regions %></div>
<div id="reports"><%= render :partial => 'reports',   :object => @reports %></div>
```

Comment: (Note, I am not flagging this yet since it has the key answer, but...) While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, you are right, link rot might occur. I will update the answer as soon as I get some time.

Comment: Muchos gracias (or other butchered thanks from an English speaker).

Comment: de nada :) (dont know if it is the accurate response)