# Rails select_tag with ajax action (Rails 3 and jQuery)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following select list.

```
<%= select_tag "project_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, "id", "title") %>
```

When the user selects an option from the above list, the list below should be populated with values from database based on the above selection.

```
<%= select_tag "version_id", options_from_collection_for_select(??project.versions??, "id", "title") %>
```

I think i should make use of the onchange event, but i have no idea on how to use it. 
Someone help me please.
Thanks!

Comment: See this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472045/multilevel-select-on-rails)

Comment: @rubyprince I have written about rails 3(!!). The remote_function doesn't exist in Rails 3

Comment: oh..sorry, in that case you can replace the onchange function with something in jQuery...I will post an answer with it...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
function update_versions_div(project_id) {  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/update_versions",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"project_id" : project_id},
    dataType: "html"
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#versionsDiv").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
def edit
  @projects = Project.all
  @versions = Version.all
end

def update_versions
  @versions = Version.where(project_id => params[:project_id]).all
  render :partial => "versions", :object => @versions
end
```

**View**

```
<%= select_tag "project_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, "id", "title"), :prompt => "Select a project", :onchange => "update_versions_div(this.value)" %>
<div id="versionsDiv">
  <%= render :partial => 'versions', :object => @versions %>
</div>
```

**Partial**: _version.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag "version_id", options_from_collection_for_select(versions, "id", "title"), :prompt => "Select a version" %>
```

Also add a route for `/update_versions` in your routes.rb

```
match "/update_versions" => "<controller>#update_versions"
```

Here, you should replace `<controller>` with name of the controller.

I havent tested the code, so there may be errors.

**Update**

PullMonkey has updated the code with Rails 3 example, which is obviously superior than this code. Please checkout http://pullmonkey.com/2012/08/11/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails-3/ also

Comment: Few improvements to this in terms of security and active record handling:

`@versions = Version.where('project_id = ?', params[:project_id]).first`
The where clause currently has a security flaw. Putting the string directly in could leave the query open to malicious content. Furthermore it is currently grabbing the ActiveRecord:Relation and not the object itself. Therefore adding a first method will fix this.

Comment: Hi @JellyFishBoy..there are 2 things here:

- `Version.where(project_id => params[:project_id])` - this `where` clause does not leave a security flaw, as far as I know. I am not putting the string directly, but, instead is passing a hash. It is the idiomatic way of writing conditions in Rails. Rails does the security handling, if we provide it as a hash. See [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

Comment: @JellyFishBoy..About the `.first`, my intention is not to get the first record, but to get all the records, with the project id. You are right to say, that it returns an activerecord relation and it will fire the query right away, but this activerecord relation will fire the query as soon as methods like `inspect`, `each` are called against it. So, the code will work, but I agree that it is better to call explicitely. I will add that.