# Change Value in a f.text_field, after choosing an option in f.collection_select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, maybe the title can't explain it well but i have a form with these lines

```
- f.collection_select(:client, Client.all, :name, :name)%>  
 - f.text_field :nit
```

I need to change in the `f.text_field` the `:nit` value from my `Client` table, according to the chosen Client in the `f.collection_select`.

Any ideas please??

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this sample code for ajax:

in view Ex:

```
 select_tag "client", options_from_collection_for_select(Client.all, "name", "title"), :prompt => "Select a client", :onchange => "update_text_box(this.value)"
```

text_field:

```
text_field_tag :nit,"",:id => "nit"
```

in script file:

```
function update_text_box(client_id) {  
 jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/update_text_box",
  type: "GET",
  data: {"client_id" : client_id},
  dataType: "text"
 success: function(data) {
  jQuery("#nit").val(data);
 }
});
```

}

Now ajax request will go when changing the select_tag.then you have to write logic in your action,finally you have to return the value.like

```
render :text => some_value.
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945529/rails-select-tag-with-ajax-action-rails-3-and-jquery#answer-7952315)

Comment: Thank you! where should i put this?? i don't know absolutely anything 'bout ajax @Kingston

Answer (score 0):

Assign `id` selector to your `collection_select` and using that selector define an `on change` function in client side which will call an action through ajax and fetch the required values from database

Comment: do u have any example or web where i can check basic ajax? i have no idea 'bout it =/