# Is their any way?I could get the value of dropdown to use in controller using onchange event handler in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to call a method using *onchange* event handler when a user changes the value on a dropdown.Below is the code for my dropdown box.

```
<%= select_tag :name,options_for_select(@tests.map{|u| [u.name]}.uniq),:onchange => 'update_dropdown(:name)' %>
```

In the controller i want a method.which takes the value of selection in dropdown as paramater:
Below code searches database for the document with value of the parameter given from view.And return the document.What are the changes i have to make to get the selection in the controller as the dropdown values are changed!

```
def update_dropdown(name)
    @drop = Test.where("name" => name)
end
```

How to get the selection value from view into the controller as parameter?
I has a mongoDatabase with documents(row) consisting key named:*name*.I has 4 unique values under key *name*.I want user to select the value using dropdown.As the user selected the dropdown.Without page refresh the documents consisting values selected with the key *name* should be displayed.
Ex:under key *name*.I has four values for 200 documents.named:
 ["value1","value2","value3","value4"].These values are the options
 for dropdown menu.If user selected any of the values.The documents consisting value for key *name* should be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to make ajax call on onchange event. Here is a link to a helpful answer
[stackoverflow.com/a/7952315/4136098](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7952315/4136098)

Comment: Is their any other way to get selection from dropdown in view into controller as parameter or any other way?I want to get the value into name parameter in the controller.
in `update_dropdown(name)`.I want `name` to be the selected value in the selection.

Comment: no need of passing name parameter in `update_dropdown(name)`. You can get the selected value in `update_dropdown` method with `this.val()`

Answer (score 3):

> How to get the selection value from view into the controller as parameter

Only way is to *send* the data through either an HTTP or Ajax (XML) request.

Because you've not explained your [`user story`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) very well, I'll explain the overall schematics on how to get it to work...

---

**Stateless**

HTTP makes Rails applications [*stateless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) - meaning that each time you send interactions to it, it will have to rebuild the user environment each time (this is why `sessions` are so important to Rails).

This means that each time you want to invoke new actions / methods, you have to send a *request* to your server. The request can be sent over several protocols (`HTTP`, `XML` and `Websockets`) - each has the same pattern: `Request > Logic > Output`

Thus, if you want to send data to your controller, you'll have to either have a full page refresh (follow the above pattern), or send the data via ajax.

---

[**Ajax**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

In this case I'd recommend using `ajax` to send a request to your controller.

```
# View
<%= select_tag :name,options_for_select(@tests.map{|u| [u.name]}.uniq), id: "select" %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#select", function(e) {
   $.get("/controller/update_dropdown", {id: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
      # Do something here
   });
});
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :controller do
   get :update_dropdown, on: :collection #-> url.com/controller/update_dropdown
end

#app/controllers/controller_controller.rb
class ControllerController < ApplicationController
   def update_dropdown
      # params[:id] will be available
      @test = Test.find params[:id]
      render json: @test.to_json
   end
end
```

Comment: nice to see you after long time bro. as always well explained

Comment: Been working on some intense projects which have now cooled down a little :p

Comment: @RichPeck.Can i use partials and load the view into other view?
Example:I has `index.html.erb` and `_show.html.erb`.`_show.html.erb` has the content that should be loaded on change in dropdown.Is it possible to load the content of the `_show.html.erb` in `index.html.erb` without `index.html.erb`.

Comment: Depends whether you want to pull the data from the backend or not

Comment: I am pulling data from backend into `_show.html.erb` page and rendering it into `index.html.erb`.