# show next select box based on previous selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}     
<%= f.collection_select :sub_category, SubCategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true} %>
```

I want to show only category specific sub_category based on category selection. How to achieve this in ruby on rails using jquery.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7952315/1581358

Comment: Please add the rendered HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `onChange` function.

```
<%= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {onchange: "getSubCategory();"} %>
<%= f.collection_select :sub_category, {}, {prompt: true} %>
```

Add this function into `application.js`

```
function getSubCategory() {
  var currentCategory = $('#category :selected').val(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/categories/'+ currentCategory +'/get_sub_categories',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#sub_category').html('');
      for (i in data.sub_categories) {
        var sub_category = data.sub_categories[i];
        if (sub_category != undefined) {
          $('#sub_category').append("<option value=\""+sub_category.id+"\">"+sub_category.name+"</option>");
        }  
      }
    } 
 });      
}
```

You should add a route and action as well

`Route`

```
resources(:categories) do
  collection do
    get(':category_id/get_sub_categories', action: :get_sub_categories)
  end
end
```

`categories_controller.rb`

```
def get_sub_categories
  if params[:category_id]
    category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    # Assuming you have one-to-many relationship between category and sub_categories.
    sub_categories = category.sub_categories 
    render json: {sub_categories: sub_categories}
  end 
end
```

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks @SpunkyLive

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. on category drop down change event you have to call js request and that request return sub categories based on category that you select

```
$("#category_id").change(function(){
  var category_id = $('#category_id').val()
  url = "/some_url?category_id=" + category_id
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    var set_sub_category;
    set_sub_category = $("#sub_category_id");
    set_sub_category.empty();
    opt = $("<option/>");
    opt.attr("value", "");
    opt.appendTo(set_sub_category);
    opt.text("---Select Sub Categories---");
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      var opt;
      opt = $("<option/>");
      opt.attr("value", value[1]);
      opt.text(value[0]);
      opt.appendTo(set_sub_category);
    });
  });
});
```

Controller Look Likes

```
def some_url
  @data = []
  @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category_id])
  if @category
   @data = @category.sub_categories.map{|b| [b.name,b.id]}
  end
  render json: @data
end
```

Comment: Thanks @bk chovatiya